# Callbacks with array

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I am trying to setup the following method to perform the success block once all the show.getVideosForShow() success blocks have been performed and all videos appended. Note: show.getVideosForShow() is asynchronous and could take a few seconds to get a result.
Could someone please provide some assistance?

```
private func getNextVideoRecommendations(success: ([Video]) -> ()) {
    var relatedVideos = [Video]()
    if let relatedShows = self.videoCurrentlyPlaying?.show?.getShowsWithSameGenre(fetchLimit: 3) {
        for show in relatedShows {
            show.getVideosForShow(tvSeason: nil, longForm: true, sortType: VideoSort.Latest, success: { (videos: [Video]) in
                print("Found Related Show: \(show.title)")
                if videos.count > 0 {
                    relatedVideos.append(videos[0])
                }
            })
        }
        print("Finished all operations")
        success(relatedVideos)
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks good provide more details what you want to achieve & is there any tableview or collection structure you are using ?

Comment: I want success(relatedVideos) to be called when all getVideosForShow sucessblocks have been completed. Currently it will call the success(relatedVideos) block immediately. Yes the results will be used to populate a collection view later on, however that is unrelated to this issue.

Comment: then you have to use a `completionhandler` for `getNextVideoRecommendations` method and call success(relatedvideos) from where you are call `getNextVideoRecommendations`

Comment: Or a workaround will be to use for loop like `for (index, show) in relatedShows {` & check for condition `if index == relatedShows.count-1` at the last of for loop to call `success(relatedVideos)`

Comment: The completionhandler is success(). See method signature. The problem is, how do you know when all the getVideosForShow completionHandlers (success block) has been called?

Comment: You should call `success(relatedVideos)` where you are calling your `getNextVideoRecommendations` upon completion

Comment: I've tried that logic, still doesnt work

Comment: Can you share that code where you tried that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111181/discussion-between-smashkon-and-muhammad-yawar-ali).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good use case for [dispatch groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25), which allow you to submit another block once all your operations have finished:

```
private func getNextVideoRecommendations(success: ([Video]) -> ()) {
    var relatedVideos = [Video]()
    if let relatedShows = self.videoCurrentlyPlaying?.show?.getShowsWithSameGenre(fetchLimit: 3) {
        let group = dispatch_group_create()
        for show in relatedShows {
            dispatch_group_enter(group)  // start tracking one unit of work
            show.getVideosForShow(tvSeason: nil, longForm: true, sortType: VideoSort.Latest, success: { (videos: [Video]) in
                print("Found Related Show: \(show.title)")
                if videos.count > 0 {
                    relatedVideos.append(videos[0])
                }
                dispatch_group_leave(group)  // finish one unit of work
            })
        }
        dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  // and when done...
            print("Finished all operations")
            success(relatedVideos)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. Just for future reference, is it possible to do this using NSOperationQueue as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use [dependencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW27) between operations to make your final operation execute only once all the others have finished.

Comment: Would you be able to send me a code snippet for that if you have a chance please? I tried it myself using dependencies but I'm pretty sure did it wrong

Comment: If you're having trouble and can show what you've tried, you might want to ask a different question. The basics are probably `NSBlockOperation` to execute the final success callback, and using `addDependency` before you put it in an operation queue.

Comment: I tried creating block operations for the "Finished all operations" and then created block operations for inside the success block of show.getVideosForShow. But It doesn't quite work